# Facebook FQL not return all friends in my friends list

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching list of friends in Graph API or FQL - Appears to be missing some friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135053/fetching-list-of-friends-in-graph-api-or-fql-appears-to-be-missing-some-friend)

I did a FQL query for my friends

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

It returned 161 friends while my facebook shows 163.
I looked through the list and noticed two contacts were missing. I can't see anything special about these friends to explain why they're not on the FQL query's list.

Any ideas on why this is happpening?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in front end facebook is showing also deactivated friends as described in comments [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/372544796150963) while with fql you will get list of friends without deactivated accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue. To my knowledge, friends who have deliberately blocked all app activity will additionally not show up in this query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Paging your query by specifying Offsets to your query.

As such, when querying the following tables and connections, use time-based paging instead of “offset” to ensure you are getting back as many results as possible with each call. For these Graph API connections, use the “since” and “until” parameters (e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/chickfila/posts?until=1298508006)

For these FQL tables, use a WHERE clause that paginates using their “timestamp”/”created_time” column (e.g. “SELECT message, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = 21543405100 AND created_time < 1299634732”)

You can also refer this for more examples
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/